# CSS grid. Square cells. Width of the cols to adjust to the height of the rows to get square cell

Tags: css, grid

I need the width of the columns to adjust to the height of the rows to get a square cell.

E.g. I have a 3/4 grid. This grid should be responsive and stretch to the **height** of the parent container.
For example, the parent container has a height of **100vh**, I want to make a grid with 3 rows, these rows should **adjust to the height** of the parent container and 4 columns should be created automatically.
**The cells should be with 1/1 ratio of square shape**.

I use `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);` and `grid-auto-flow: column;` on grid container and try to use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` for cells.

The problem I am facing is when I use the `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;`, **the height of the cell adjusts to the width**(see screenshots). And the grid gets bigger and overflows the parent element...
But **I need the width to adjust to the height.**

[image]

[image]

**Expected result:**
[image]

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either the elements adjust to the width or the height,,, not both. Perhaps you could show us what this is **supposed to look like**?

Comment: I've added expected result screen and updated description. Let me know if there's anything left unclear. Thank you.